# AJAX: How do I get the label and value of a field to be different?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the below two files.
How do I get AJAX to populate a label and a value

For example if value is Chicago, IL. How do I get the value to be only Chicago on Submitting the form?

Below the field populates as, for example, Chicago, IL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center"></h2>
   <br /><br />
   <label>Search Country</label>
   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type City Name" />
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#city').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"TypeaheadTest2.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

Below is file TypeaheadTest2.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM state WHERE state LIKE '".$request."%' OR city LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row['city'] . ' ' . $row['state'];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you right, you are so close to what you are expecting.

I see that you are concatenating the city and state name on the server side. But you want to display only city name on typeahead options.

I would suggest you pass on the city name and state name as separate attributes of an object from PHP and then use them as you want on Javascript side.

Here is the sample code,
PHP:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    $request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM state WHERE state LIKE '".$request."%' OR city LIKE '%".$request."%'
    ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $data = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = array('city'=>$row['city'], 'state'=>$row['state']);
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#city').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"TypeaheadTest2.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{query:query},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item){
                        return item.city;
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```